# Text box Id is not getting validated by document.getElementById()

Tags: javascript, checkbox, textbox, isenabled

I have written a JS function in .jsp file to enable textbox when checkBox is checked. But the `document.getElementById()` is  simply not working. If I put `alert(document.getElementById("textBoxId"));`,it returns null. Here is my code.

```
function enableColumns() 
{
    if (checkBoxId.checked == true)
    {   
        document.getElementById("column1Id").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("column2Id").disabled = false;
    }
}
```

Also I have tried other methods like `setAttribute`, `removeAttribute`, `window.onload` for the same. Nothing is working. Please guide me in the above problem.

Comment: That means no element with that id exists at the time the function gets called.. however it is hard to judge without the actual DOM.

Comment: Are you sure that exists and element with this id="column1Id" ?